# i want to call percent() in finaloutput() ,percent() is a subfunction of another function ,is there any way to do this .?

Tags: python, function

sir i want to use a subfunction in another function. 
i want to call percent() in finaloutput()  ,percent() is a subfunction of  another function ,is there any way to do this .??

```
count1=0
count2=0
p=0
p2=0
p1=0
def findpercents():
       print("_______________find percents__________________")
       global count1,count2,p,p1,p2
       def percent():
            p=((count1+count2)/10)*100
            print("totalcb%=",p)
            p1=(count1/10)*100
            print("malecb%=",p1)
            p2=(count2/10)*100
            print("femalecb%=",p2)
       percent()    

def  finaloutput():
        print("______________final output______________")
       #i want to call percent() in this function,which is a subfunction of  
         #another function.
       #def percent(p,p1,p2,count1,count2):
       #percent(p,p1,p2,count1,count2)
```

Comment: Just don't define `percent` in `findpercents`, there's no reason to do it.

Comment: Actually this is an example code.i have to use a subfunction in  several different functions. So i am searching for this type of cocept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the `def percent()` out of `findpercents()`. Having one function defined within another only means that that function will only be defined for an element inside that parent function. When the call to the parent function finishes executing the function will become undefined, just like any other variable in there.

```
count1=0
count2=0
p=0
p2=0
p1=0
def percent():
    global count1,count2,p,p1,p2
    p=((count1+count2)/10)*100
    print("totalcb%=", p)
    p1=(count1/10)*100
    print("malecb%=", p1)
    p2=(count2/10)*100
    print("femalecb%=", p2)

def findpercents():
    print("_______________find percents__________________")
    percent()    

def  finaloutput():
    print("______________final output______________")
    percent()
```

EDIT: In response to OP's question in the comments, yes there is another way of doing this. You could make `percent` a global variable inside the `findpercents` function. In order for it to be defined you would need to run `findpercents` first, but it would work.

```
count1=0
count2=0
p=0
p2=0
p1=0
def findpercents():
    print("_______________find percents__________________")
    global count1,count2,p,p1,p2
    global percent
    def percent():
        p=((count1+count2)/10)*100
        print("totalcb%=",p)
        p1=(count1/10)*100
        print("malecb%=",p1)
        p2=(count2/10)*100
        print("femalecb%=",p2)
    percent()    

def finaloutput():
    print("______________final output______________")
    percent()
```

However, it is very rare that you would need to use functions defined this way in python, and in general most people would recommend avoiding it.

Comment: Yes this is the other way to solve this but is there any method to call a subfunction in another function?just in experimental way.

Comment: @Shubhamkumar Yes there is, see my edit for the code and explanation.

Comment: Yes thanks for ur valuable response......sir i am writing a code for biomedical application.because of large length of code and a lot of functions, i was trying to apply this concept there,it will surely reduce my code length without  altering any of complexities.

Comment: This method likely wouldn't reduce the code length, however it might reduce the amount stored in memory.